# Apple configurator on Yosemite

Tags: macos, ios, apple-configurator

Ok I need to install Apple Configurator because a colleague of mine is developing some kind of app and as far as I understood he needs it to put the app on his phone to test it.

I am running Yosemite on a late 2013 MBP and don't plan on updating to "El Capitan".

Apparently Apple has updated Apple Configurator to v2.2? and since v2.0 they don't support Yosemite. They have deleted every link to older versions of the program and I can't find it anywhere. There literally is no trace of v1.72(supposed to be the last version that supported Yosemite).

Do you have any idea how can I install whatever version of Apple Configurator on Yosemite? If you have other ideas about transfering an app from yosemite to iOS8 that'd work too. Thanks!